# Creating multiple unit tests from a loop in Java

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, junit4

I'm writing unit tests for my (small) program, and the test cases are specified in around 30 different files.
To test it, all I need is a loop that goes over all the files, parse them, and execute what's needed.

The problem is that in that case, all of my tests will be considered as one, since it's all in the same function with the `@Test` notation.
Is it possible to split it somehow without having to have a separate function for each test file?

The problem with all the tests as one test case, is that I can't see which test case fail the process; and if one fails it fail the rest (I'll get 1 test failed instead of 5/30 failed)

I'm currently using JUnit (4.12), but I'm not obligated to keep using it, so I can switch framework if there's a better solution.

Thanks!

Example:

```
public class MyTests {
    @Test
    public void testFromFiles {
        // loop through all the files
    }
}

output: 1 test run successfully
```

---

**Update:** The selected answer worked great for me, and I added another solution with JUnit 5 (instead of 4), in case it will help someone.

Comment: Just throwing this out there... why?

Comment: Why what? didn't got you. Why the test cases are in files? why I want to separate them?

Comment: Why you think you want to run your tests in this way?

Comment: What are you suggesting?

Comment: That's the thing.  Without knowing what the underlying problem is, I don't know what to suggest.

Comment: I prefer to have an exact summary of each test case, and not all of them as one, since in that way it's harder to know which one failed, and if one fail - it fails the rest (something that will now occur if they were separated).

Comment: Don't you use a (server-side) build server like Jenkins including Maven, Gradle, ant, whatever? Your IDE should be capable of running those tests as well including some kind of report...

Comment: I agree: you are waisting your time here. Learn how off the shelf product implementations work... Instead of trying to invent your own wheel! Seriously: having many testcase and getting helpful information on failed ones is a SOLVED problem.

Comment: It's a small program I just want to test. I'm not using any build server or have any build/deployment process. I've asked because I didn't thought I need some robustic product to solve that thing, and believed it's something that is possible to achieve fairly simply.

Comment: @GhostCat wasn't trying to invent, I thought it's possible but I just haven't found how.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this way:

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class EdiTest {

    @SuppressWarnings("WeakerAccess")
    @Parameterized.Parameter(value = 0)
    public String model;

    @SuppressWarnings("WeakerAccess")
    @Parameterized.Parameter(value = 1)
    public String filename;

    @Parameterized.Parameters(name = "{index}: testEDI({0}, {1})")
    public static Collection<Object[]> data() {
        return Arrays.asList(new Object[][]{
                {"753", "edi753_A.edi"},
                {"753", "edi753_B.edi"},
                {"754", "edi754.edi"},
                {"810", "edi810-withTax.edi"},
                {"810", "edi810-withoutTax.edi"},
        });
    }

    @Before
    public void setUpContext() throws Exception {
        TestContextManager testContextManager = new TestContextManager(getClass());
        testContextManager.prepareTestInstance(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void testEDI() throws IOException {
        String edi = IOUtils.toString(ClassLoader.getSystemResource(filename));
        EdiConverter driver = ediConverterProvider.getConverter(model);

        // your test code here
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll have a look at that

Comment: Working  Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

With JUnit 5 and [Dynamic Tests](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-dynamic-tests):

- [Basic example](https://reinhard.codes/2017/10/09/parameterized-tests-with-junit-5-jupiter/):

  ```
  class DynamicTests {

    @TestFactory
    List<DynamicTest> createSomeTests() {

      return Arrays.asList(
        DynamicTest.dynamicTest("First dynamically created test",
          () -> assertTrue(true)),

        DynamicTest.dynamicTest("Second dynamically created test",
          () -> assertTrue(true))
      );
    }
  }
  ```
- Example of getting and filtering all test files:

  ```
  class MyTestsClass {
      @TestFactory
      List<DynamicTest> runAllTestFiles() {
          List<DynamicTest> list = new ArrayList<DynamicTest>();
          try (Stream<Path> paths = Files.walk(Paths.get("tests_dir"))) {
              List<Path> files = paths
                      .filter(path -> path.getFileName().toString().endsWith(".mytests"))
                      .collect(Collectors.toList());
              files.forEach(file -> list.add(
                      DynamicTest.dynamicTest(
                          file.getFileName().toString(), 
                          () -> testFileWithSomeAsserts(file))
              ));
          } catch (IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }

          return list;
      }
  }
  ```

The `@TestFactory` works differently than regular tests, and `@BeforeEach` / `@AfterEach` cannot be used in that case:

> ***Dynamic Test Lifecycle***
>
> The execution lifecycle of a dynamic test is quite different than it is for a standard `@Test` case. Specifically, there are no lifecycle callbacks for individual dynamic tests. This means that `@BeforeEach` and `@AfterEach` methods and their corresponding extension callbacks are executed for the `@TestFactory` method but not for each dynamic test. In other words, if you access fields from the test instance within a lambda expression for a dynamic test, those fields will not be reset by callback methods or extensions between the execution of individual dynamic tests generated by the same `@TestFactory` method.

[More examples in the official documentation](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-dynamic-tests-examples).